# Get corresponding PR from Github deployment status webhook

Tags: node.js, github-api, probot

I am creating a Github app that listens for `deployment_status.created` webhook events. The webhook is triggered when a PR is automatically deployed (using a 3rd party Github app).

When the deployment has a certain state, e.g. success, I want to add a comment to the corresponding PR.

My example code:

```js
app.on('deployment_status.created', async (context) => {
    const deployment_status = context.payload.deployment_status

    if (deployment_status.state === 'success') {
      // TODO: comment on the corresponding PR
    }
  })
```

How do I get the corresponding PR?

NB. There seems to be nothing in the payload for it (https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#deployment_status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed, seems like `deployment_status` payload is not offering the pull request URL or `id` so you can directly post a comment.

What I think it's available is the `ref` or `sha` in the payload: https://github.com/octokit/webhooks/blob/6a8fec1a9e76780bba12b75291be104a1697d300/schema.d.ts#L1774-L1775

With those you can list the PR's associated I think: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-pull-requests-associated-with-a-commit

Still I don't know if it would be the best solution.

I invite you to post this issue (and look for potential existing ones) in https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/discussions/categories/q-a I think you will get faster feedback there.